# PHP in_array not working with current array structure

Tags: php, sql, arrays, function

I am using a custom method to return a query as an array.

This is being used to check if a discount code posted is in the DB.

The array ends up as example:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [code] => SS2015
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [code] => SS2016
    )

)
```

So when I am trying to do:

```
if ( ! in_array($discount_code, $valid_codes)) {

}
```

Its not working. Is there a way I can still use the function for query to array I am using and check if its in the array?

No issues, I can make a plain array of the codes but just wanted to keep things consistent.

Comment: I think `array_search` is better to use.

Comment: I think your array code is broken. you can't have the same key with different values in an assoc array.

Comment: Show the **exact** input from `$discount_code` and the exact values from `$valid_codes`

Comment: Fixed the array example using a  print_r of the actual array.

Comment: Because it is object of array. That's why it is not searching.

Comment: Can you change your Array to have not numeric keys but the [code] as the array key? Then you could use in_array(). But the [code] values have to be unique between all objects.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) (serialize data to json) and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php) (return associative array from serialized json, if secondary param is true). Also [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) gets values by field name. so we have array of values in 1 dimensional array, then let's check with in_array.

```
function isInCodes($code, $codes) {
    $codes = json_encode($codes); // serialize array of objects to json
    $codes = json_decode($codes, true); // unserialize json to associative array
    $codes = array_column($codes, 'code'); // build 1 dimensional array of code fields
    return in_array($code, $codes); // check if exists
}

if(!isInCodes($discount_code, $valid_codes)) {
// do something
}
```

Comment: That is much better so I upvoted it. And it is a good idea not to just give a working solution, but also to describe why OP's attempt failed. And there are other [markdown capabilities](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) that can allow you to create far more visually appealing and readable posts (but it is obviously not a compulsory obligation to do so with every post). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I Appreciate Your recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to identify the objects having property `code` equal with `$discount_code`:

```
$in_array = array_filter(
    $valid_codes,
    function ($item) use ($discount_code) {
        return $item->code == $discount_code;
    }
);

if (! count($in_array)) {
    // $discount_code is not in $valid_codes
}
```

If you need to do the same check many times, in different files, you can convert the above code snippet to a function:

```
function code_in_array($code, array $array)
{
    return count(
        array_filter(
            $array,
            function ($item) use ($code) {
                return $item->code == $code;
            }
        )
    ) != 0;
}


if (! code_in_array($discount_code, $valid_codes)) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
foreach ($haystack as $item) {
    if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
}
```

then

```
echo in_array_r("SS2015", $array) ? 'found' : 'not found';
```

Answer (score 0):

why not solve it as a school task - fast and easy:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($valid_codes); $i++) if ($valid_codes[$]->code == $discount_code) break;
if ( ! ($i < count($valid_codes))) {  // not in array
}
```